# Export Random Forest model from R to OpenCV

Tags: r, opencv, translate

How would I export a Random Forest model created with R into OpenCV?

I ask because I prototype in R (specifically Random Forest), but would like to be able to run my model in OpenCV due to the latter's speed with processing large images.

Comment: I'm assuming this was marked OT because it borders on a recommendation for a library and/or tutorial. I'm asking the question because I don't know how to accomplish this task given what I've found on the topic. I'd like to know how others have accomplished this task, or how they would do so given the present state of knowledge. I've rephrased the question to be more direct, and eliminated any mention of libraries I thought would be useful for accomplishing the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively, PMML is a one-way street. It is rather easy to export models from any framework-specific representation (eg. OpenCV, R) to PMML representation, but not so easy to do the opposite. The idea is that once you have your model in PMML representation, you should typically consume it using a dedicated PMML scoring engine, not some other technology.

In your case, what you want to do is to translate between [OpenCV's `CvRTrees` class](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html) and [R's `randomForest` data structure](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf). You are probably better off by developing a direct two-way converter (ie. `CvRTrees` <-> `randomForest`) than using PMML as a middleman (ie. `CvRTrees` <-> `PMML` <-> `randomForest`). This decision is easy to rationalize, because at the moment, there is only the `randomForest` -> `PMML` conversion component available. Therefore, it is probably less effort to develop two missing conversion components (ie. the former "direct" conversion scenario) than three missing conversion components (ie. the latter "mediated" conversion scenario).

To keep things simple, I would recommend to achieve "model portability" by using a shared training dataset. That is, if you need a OpenCV's RF model, then you would train it directly using the `CvRTrees::train` method call, and if you need a R's RF model, then you would train it directly using the `randomForest()` method call.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up wrt to PMML. As for the last comment, I'm not sure that will work for me as the model trained in R uses `caret` and a few other neat tricks to derive the final model. I don't think it would be possible to replicate my model tuning in R with OpenCV's RF implementation.

Comment: For completeness, can you explain why it isn't easy to go from PMML to a given framework (e.g., PMML -> OpenCV)? It was my understanding this was what PMML was built for.

Comment: The main problem is "mismatching" vocabularies. PMML may contain expressions that cannot be represented in OpenCV or R, and vice versa. As for the `caret` package then it basically performs a search in RF parameter space (eg. `ntree`, `mtry` and so on). Once you know what the best parameters are, you can transfer them "manually" to OpenCV.