# How can I convert Random Forest algorithm into universal data type?

Tags: r, xml, random-forest, r-caret, pmml

I developed a Random Forest regression algorithm in R using CARET. I need to export the algorithm as universal data-type (for instance xml), so it can be implemented on a different platform.

So far, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464604/export-random-forest-model-from-r-to-opencv) where `pmml` is recommanded to get a xml, but it only works if one has a "*Random Forest formula*" (results from function *RandomForest*). However, it does not lead me to equal performance as I used `caret::train`, which results into a "*large train object*"

I found another package `r2pmml`, which shall convert my model into a pmml but I cannot install the package (probably outdated, as I cannot install from repository or on other Rstudio versions).

Here is how I create my regression model

```
 rf.model.tuned <- train(response ~ ., data = training,
                    method = "rf", importance=TRUE,
                    trControl =  trainControl (method= "repeatedcv", 
                                 number=5, repeats = 5))
```

Anyone an idea how I can use regression models outside the R environment?

Comment: Try the `pmml` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmml/index.html

Comment: sorry but why would you suggest something I mentioned in my inital description as not appropiate?

Comment: `r2pmml` is different than `pmml`

Comment: Im aware of that: "So far, I only found this thread where pmml is recommanded to get a xml, but it only works if one has a "Random Forest formula" (results from function RandomForest). However, it does not lead me to equal performance as I used caret::train, which results into a "large train object"

Comment: "I cannot install the r2pmml package" - This package is not available in CRAN and/or RStudio repositories. You need to install it from GitHub, exactly as detailed in r2pmml README file.

Comment: I wanted to avoid loading github packages with devtools due to restrictions on the PC but I managed to install <r2pmml> manually, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export caret-trained Random Forest models with the [r2pmml](https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml) package.